# HTTPS Requests Error In Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, https, request

I have been using Ruby for some time now, but I'd still consider myself relatively a beginner.

I have been trying to make a program in Ruby that uses web requests as one of it's base functions. While this works fine with urls that do not use https, whenever I send a request to a url with https, it fails.

When I use `request = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))` for http, the response is fine, just what I need.

However, with HTTPS, I have tried everything from pure ruby ([net/http](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS)) to external gems ([http.rb](https://github.com/httprb/http)), and nothing will work. I keep getting the same error every time: `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

I am looking to be able to do the same thing as the http requests (using `request.body` to get the html, and `request.code` to get the status code).

If anyone is able to help me with this then that would be great.

### Edit:

I have now figured out that Ruby is unable to see my CA certs, and I wish to know how to point ruby at them.

When using Cygwin, I am able to use irb and from within there I am able to use HTTPS requests, but not otuside of Cygwin.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to have a look to gems like [`ruby-client`](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)?

Comment: @mabe02 I'll take and look and see how that works, but I'm like 90% sure that it's Ruby can't find my CA certs.

Comment: @mabe02 rest-client (I'm assumint that's what you mean in your comment) Isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Yes, it is a temorary fix, but I want my ruby app to be use only net/http in the future.